# How to make gradient in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, gradient

I need to make different gradient color for different lines

For example, now I have two lines, but both of them has the same gradient color (blue):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    },
    {
        data: [10, 20, 79.4, 50.2, 40.0, 50.0, 110.6, 90.5, 113.4, 144.1, 75.6, 24.4]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5g3khvme/4/

I'd like to use default colors of highcharts for lines, but for blue it should be blue gradient, for black line it should be black gradient and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function of your chart to iterate the series and update the fillColor based on the `serie.color`

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'areaspline'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    },
    {
      data: [10, 20, 79.4, 50.2, 40.0, 50.0, 110.6, 90.5, 113.4, 144.1, 75.6, 24.4]
    }
  ]
}, (chart) => {
  chart.series.forEach((serie) => {
    serie.update({
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
        stops: [
          [0, serie.color],
          [1, Highcharts.color(serie.color).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```